# How to remove duplicates in my array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array called array1

```
Array(
     [0] => 1,
     [1] => 2,
     [2] => 5
)
```

And another array called array2

```
Array(
     [0] => 3,
     [1] => 2,
     [2] => 7 
)
```

I need to get the array1 which is not in array2

I need to get result as

```
Array(
    [0] => 1,
    [1] => 5
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: where is 3 and 7? in you expected result

Comment: Sorry I tried array_diff but I put array_diff($array2,$array1) thats why I didn't get expected result

Comment: did you give a try to `array_diff($array1,$array2)` then ?

Answer (score 1):

Try array_unique function
e.g.

```
$fruits_list = array('Orange',  'Apple', ' Banana', 'Cherry', ' Banana');
$result = array_unique($fruits_list);
print_r($result);
```

**Ref:**

https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_unique.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 5);
$array2 = array(3, 2, 7);
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2))
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 5
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this.

```
$array = [
     0 => 1,
     1 => 2,
     2 => 5
];

unset($array[1]);
$array = array_values($array); 

print_r($array);
```

Result:
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 )

Comment: Downvoted : this is not dynamic